# How to remove/update a JSONB array element where key equals a value?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I'd like remove/replace an element from a JSONB array where a property is equal to a set value. I've found a number of functions that will accomplish this but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it without one as I have database restrictions?

Here's an example JSONB value:

```
[
  { "ID": "valuea" },
  { "ID": "valueb" },
  { "ID": "valuec" }
]
```

I'd like to remove the second array position where ID is equal to `valueb` with a single update statement. I'd imagine this could finding the position/order in the array, `jsonb_set()` to remove it.

It would also be helpful if there was a way to update the row and not just remove it. Likely a similar query, again with `jsonb_set()`.

Comment: I assume there will be more keys than just 'ID' per array element? (Else, just drop the redundant key and make it an array of strings.) Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no function to return the position of a JSON array element (yet) as of Postgres 15.

To remove a **single** matching element:

```sql
UPDATE tbl t
SET    js = t.js - (SELECT j.ord::int - 1
                    FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.js) WITH ORDINALITY j(v,ord)
                    WHERE  j.v = '{"ID": "valueb"}'
                    LIMIT  1)
WHERE  t.js @> '[{"ID": "valueb"}]'   -- optional
AND    jsonb_typeof(t.js) = 'array';  -- optional
```

This `UPDATE` uses a correlated subquery with [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).
About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Both `WHERE` clauses are optional.

- Use the filter `t.js @> '[{"ID": "valueb"}]'` to suppress (potentially expensive!) empty updates and make good use of an existing GIN index on the `jsonb` column
- Use the filter `jsonb_typeof(t.js) = 'array'` to only suppress errors from non-arrays.

Note how the outer filter includes enclosing array decorators `[]`, while the inner filter (after unnesting) does not.

To remove **all** matching elements:

```sql
UPDATE tbl t
SET    js = (SELECT jsonb_agg(j.v)
             FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.js) j(v)
             WHERE  NOT j.v @> '{"ID": "valueb"}')
WHERE  t.js @> '[{"ID": "valueb"}]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u7_aoc-s)

The second query aggregates a new array from remaining elements.

This time, the inner filter uses `@>` instead of `=` to allow for additional keys. Chose the appropriate filter.

Aside: [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) might be useful *additionally* if the array in question is actually nested, unlike your example.

Comment: Awesome. I was on the right path but I was writing with ordinality completely wrong. I appreciate your insight and support!